# Python pip install tesseract-ocr fails

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Everytime when i try to install Tesseract-ocr in pycharm there is this message [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM7DR.jpg)

How can I fix this path or do I have to fix something else?

Comment: Are you facing this error with 'Tesseract-ocr' installation only or with every package installation ?

Comment: Also curious, your question is asking about PyCharm however your screenshot is showing a path to Microsoft Visual studio. Can you elaborate on the steps you use to attempt to install it?

Comment: So i go to my Project  Then File => Settings => Project Interpreter => + then I search for Tesseract-ocr and when I install it i shows this error message Here => https://imgur.com/a/KvSiwI7

Comment: Only for this installation.

Answer (score 0):

you should download tesseract-ocr:

https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

you can try:

```
pip install tesseract-ocr

pip install tesseract
```

and you should update your visual studio c++ there:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/